# New relic does not show errors inside spring integration flows

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, newrelic, spring-integration-dsl

I have some flows like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow aFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(EventSink.INPUT)
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Event.class))
                //more stuff
                .get();
    }
}
```

When some exception occurs inside the flow (e.g. during a transformation) I see the exception in the logs, but there is nothing traced in New Relic (Error section is completely empty)

I suspect that is because the exception occurred outside a New Relic transaction, but how can I declare a transaction while using Spring Integration flows?

Comment: I'm not familiar what is New Relic. Any pointers for simple description and usage? Probably we just need to add its support into Spring Integration. Or there is indeed a way to workaround what you want to do. Thanks

Comment: It is a very popular framework for metrics and logs. It works attaching an agent to JVM and sending information to their servers. It works like a charm (without any special configuration) with Spring beans like services, controllers, repositories, etc. I think that New Relic is not aware of what is happening inside the channels, maybe because there are no transactions created, but I'm not sure.

Comment: We have Micrometer integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#metrics-management. Maybe there is some bridge from there to New Relic?

Comment: I found something that may help here: https://github.com/newrelic/micrometer-registry-newrelic . I will give it a try, thanks!